# Automatically download dependencies for haskell project?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have a course project in haskell, that depends on `MonadRandom` and `hashable` packages.

Now, whenever I clone it from git on a different computer, I have to go through a procedure, that goes somethilng like this:

```
runhaskell Main.hs
>Could not find module `Control.Monad.Random'

--Google what package Control.Monad.Random is part of... MonadRandom!
cabal install MonadRandom

runhaskell Main.hs
>Could not find module `Data.Hashable'

--Google where Data.Hashable comes from.. ok `hashable`!
cabal install hasahable

runhaskell Main.hs
> HELLO WORLD!
```

Is there a way to simplify this so I just run one command? For example python's `pip` does it with [requirements](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html):

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

If you write a .cabal file for your project, you can get it built with `cabal configure`, `cabal install --only-dependencies` and `cabal build`. (That's if you just want to build it in the current directory; if you want to install it along with all your other Haskell packages, the procedure is as simple as `cabal install`.)

You can start by running `cabal init` in your project directory — it'll ask you a bunch of questions and output an incomplete .cabal file with the easy stuff filled out for you.

Cabal is the standard build system for all Haskell projects, so you should generally write a Cabal file as early on in your project as possible.

See also [this introduction to packaging things with Cabal](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program).

Comment: Thanks. The only thing is I am not really installing my project or distributing it. I only want to record dependencies and install them... so I am not sure if cabal will work - since I change my project code every day or so (will I have to reinstall it onto the system every time?) Sorry if I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: Like I said, if you just want to build your project without installing it, you can start off with `cabal configure` and `cabal install --dependencies-only` (which only installs the dependencies of your project), and then `cabal build` whenever you change your code.

Comment: Why do I need to run `cabal configure` then?

Comment: Also, I get an error `cabal.exe: unrecognized option --dependencies-only`

Comment: It should be `--only-dependencies` instead.

Comment: @drozzy: the `cabal configure` step is needed to have the `.cabal` file parsed and dependencies recognised (since it's also feasible to use different dependencies between configuration options, OS, version of compiler, etc.).

Comment: For me, `cabal install --only-dependencies` worked, without the `configure` part. Sorry, I am hesitant in accepting your answer only because of this little trifle.

Comment: Yes, `cabal install` will automatically configure. But I don't think that configuration will persist to the `cabal build`. You only have to `cabal configure` once on each machine (until you change the Cabal file), so it's not really that big a deal; if you really want to avoid the one-time overhead, you could write a shell script (but it'd be slower, since it'd have to re-configure every build).

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want to use [Cabal](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/) for. Create a `.cabal` file for your project then run `cabal install` in your projects root directory after cloning the repo. This will get all your dependencies for you.

All big projects get a cabal file for building at some point anyhow, so you may as well start using it now.

Comment: But I don't want to install my project into the system - only install it's dependencies. Will `install` do this? Also  - do I need to run `configure`, as in @ehird's answer?

Comment: Oh yeah, `install` will actually install your project. You should use ehird's commands if you don't want to do that.